# How to address HasAuthentication error in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I wanted to create a test via Intellij. I have also integrated the jar files. However, when I perform the operation, I encounter a hasAuthentication error. If anyone has faced similar problem before, can you help me?

Selenium Has Authentication Error Image:

[image: Selenium Has Authentication Error Image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium-4 - Not able to handle HasAuthentication popup with Remote driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73290245/selenium-4-not-able-to-handle-hasauthentication-popup-with-remote-driver)

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation in [*Interface HasAuthentication*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/HasAuthentication.html) if website requires any authentication through URL then the following error occurs:

[image: HasAuthentication]

---

### Solution

To get rid of this error you need to download and integrate the ***`selenium-api`*** **jar** in your project.